# Theoretical analysis of the algorithm that returns true or false, given a probability

Tags: javascript, algorithm, probability

I want to implement a method that returns `true` with a probability of `n/m` and returns `false` with a probability of `(m-n)/m`.

For example, I want to get `true` with a probability of 7/10000.

To achieve this, I first get a random integer `n` that is under 10000 from the function `getRandomIntUnderN`. Then, I judge whether `n` is smaller than (7+1), if it is, I return `true`, `false` if not.

I have an implementation below:

```js
// 0 is included while n is not
const getRandomIntUnderN = (n) => {
    const rn = Math.random() * n
    return Math.trunc(rn)
}
// the opportunity of a truthy return value is n/m
const goAtChance = (n, m) => {
    return getRandomIntUnderN(m) < n 
}
// a opportunity of 7‰ to return true
console.log(goAtChance(7, 10000))
```

My question is: is it okay that I just judge whether `n` is under (7+1) to make a perfect probability as expected?

On one hand, numbers from 1 to 7 are not distributed discretely enough in the range from 1 to 10000: it seems there will be a bias that makes it unlikely to return a truthy value.

On the other hand, since I can get a purely random number from `getRandomIntUnderN`, the chance will not be affected by which numbers I choose to determine the return value. It can be [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], [21,22,23,24,25,26,27], [23,55,3,66,762,92,123] or whatever under 10000.

So, which opinion is right?

Comment: Why do you say (7+1) not just 7?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*numbers from 1 to 7 are not distributed discretely enough in the range from 1 to 10000*"

Comment: Btw the truncation is unnecessary

Comment: *"it seems there will be a bias that makes it unlikely to return a truthy value"*: where does this statement come from? What is "unlikely"? Does the probability of 7/10000 fall into that category of "unlikely"?

Comment: @trincot, since it's not discrete enough(concentrated in the range from 1 to 7), I have an intrinsic feeling that the real probability will be less than 7‰. I failed to express what I meant clearly.

Comment: @Bergi, "Not sure what you mean by...". It means the numbers are concentrated in a range instead of concrete.

Comment: It seems your feeling is wrong. As you say, if `getRandomIntUnderN` returns equally distributed numbers ([uniform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution)), it doesn't matter for which 7 numbers you are looking - hitting one of `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` is just as likely as hitting one of `[21,22,23,24,25,26,27]` or one of `[23,55,3,66,762,92,123]`.

Comment: The only reason it might be slightly off is that `Math.random` might not be exactly uniform - it should be [continuously uniform over `[0, 1)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution), but there's actually only a finite set of floating point numbers, so your result will be a tiny bit biased, similar to [taking the modulo of random integer from a too small range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10984974/1048572).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Then, I judge whether n is smaller than (7+1), if it is, return true, false if not.

This is not how you implemented it. Your code checks that n is less than 7, which is the correct way to do it.

> it seems there will be a bias that makes it unlikely to return a truthy value.

Where does that statement come from? Surely you can test this premise... and see how likely it is.

> the chance will not be affected by which numbers did I choose to determine the return value

This is true.

#### How to test

You can easily test what the distribution is of your implementation. You can call the function repeatedly and keep a record of the results you get, and see how that evolves over time. In statistics you get more reliable results the greater the size of your sample is.

Here is a snippet that keeps executing the `goAtChance` function and records the total number of calls and the number of `true` results. Every 10 milliseconds the results are updated on the page, including the ratio of the number of `true` over the total number. This ratio should over time converge to 0.0007 if all is well.

```js
const getRandomIntUnderN = (n) => Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
const goAtChance = (n, m) => getRandomIntUnderN(m) < n; 

let [outTotal, outHits, outRatio] = document.querySelectorAll("span");

let hits = 0; // Number of results that are true
let total = 0; // Total number of results

requestAnimationFrame(function loop() {
   let deadline = performance.now() + 10;
   do {
     hits += goAtChance(7, 10000); // boolean coerces to 0 or 1
     total++;
   } while (performance.now() < deadline);
   // Show the accumulated results
   outTotal.textContent = total;
   outHits.textContent = hits;
   outRatio.textContent = (hits / total).toFixed(8);
   requestAnimationFrame(loop); // Allow screen to update and then continue
});
```

```html
Samples: <span></span><br>
Hits: <span></span><br>
Ratio: <span></span>
```

Comment: wonderful answer and it showed me a way to solve similar problems in the future.